# Can I initialize Foundation 4 Tooltips in scope?

Tags: zurb-foundation, tooltip

I am trying to initialize Foundation 4.3.1 tooltips in scope, on a DIV class $(".some-class").foundation('tooltips'), instead of on document $(document).foundation('tooltips'). When I do this, the tooltip on a touch device (iPad), opens on tap but does not close on tap. Am I doing something wrong? How do I get the tooltip to work properly. The reason I need to do this is because Foundation tooltips conflict with ckeditor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Foundation 4.3.1 source](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v4.3.1/js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js#L37-L53) there is a condition that will handle the `touchstart` `touchend` events as hover. This condition is met automatically where `Modernizr.touch` is available.

In addition, there is also a configurable option to [disable touch events](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v4.3.1/js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js#L16) for all tooltips.

Here is a link to the Modernizr builder with touch events pre-selected: http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-load